# Internal Server Error 500.19 Plesk / IIS

Tags: iis, plesk, internal-server-error, woff, woff2

I upgraded Plesk 12.0 to 12.5 today and got a hard error that causes my website to be unreachable.

If I open the website on the server i get the following error message:
[image]

It says that it that a second entry of the type "mimeType" with the key attribute .woff cant be added.

Can someone help me with that error?

**UPDATE**
I deleted the entries in the file which called the error and now it is working again. What i am asking myself: was it the right way to delete this error? Don't want to have any further errors in the future because of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your config like this:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/font-sfnt" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```